# zero bytes avro file exception

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, avro, spark-avro

I am currently using avro 1.8.2 to write log events. I am observing certain very rare cases where my DataFileWriter is actually writing out 0 bytes file. As far as i understand a valid avro file should always have header.
The code snippet looks like :

```
String id = uuidGenerate();
String tmpPath = prefix + id + ".tmp"
String publishedPath = prefix + id + ".log" 
DatumWriter<MySchema> datumWriter = new SpecificDatumWriter<>();
DataFileWriter<MySchema> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(datumWriter);
create(schema, file) 
for (MySchema record : data) {
    writer.write(record);
}
writer.close();
Files.move(tmpPath, publishedPath, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

What i observe is 0 bytes .log file , assuming the move is atomic , i think somehow i am writing corrupted 0 byte avro .tmp files which are being persisted on disk as 0 bytes .log files.
On reading back the 0 byte file i get following exception :

> java.io.IOException: Not a data file. 62512:  at
>   org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:102)
>   62513:  at
>   org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.(DataFileStream.java:84)

Has any one encountered such 0 byte corrupted avro files before. What was the cause since going through code i don't clearly understand how is this even possible as trying to reproduce locally i always get few bytes with header.
Do i actually need to fsync my avro files after closing them and moving them atomically. Is the move moving file before any metadata or header is being synced to disk. (my environment is Google compute instance on GCP)
Any insights on debugging this would really help.

Comment: Are you attempting to write the file on Cloud Storage?

Comment: no to local disk of GCE , i observe 0 byte files on local disks for GCE